# python index in 2d matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-indexing

Given the following code:

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
```

My understanding was the following lines are identical:

```
mat[:3][1:2]
mat[:3,1:2]
```

But they are not. Why?

Comment: `mat[x][y]` is the same as `mat[x, y]` only if `x` is a scalar, i.e. if it selects one item on the first dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only specify one dimension in your slicing syntax, only one dimension will be sliced. In NumPy, dimensions in indexing are typically separated by `","`.

For a 2d array, you may substitute "row" with "dimension 1" and "column" with "dimension 2". In your example, `mat[:3]` slices the first 3 rows. The subsequent indexer `[1:2]`, slices the first of those 3 rows.

With your second example, `[:3, 1:2]` slices rows and columns simultaneously.

You may find it helpful to look at the shapes of your results:

```
mat[:3].shape       # (3, 5)
mat[:3][1:2].shape  # (1, 5)
mat[:3,1:2].shape   # (3, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

The first one `mat[:3][1:2]` will first take `mat[:3]` and then apply `[1:2]`:

```
mat[:3]
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
# mat[:3][1:2] => array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

While the second one (`mat[:3,1:2]`) states:

lines up to `3`

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Columns `1` to `2`

```
 array([[ 2],
       [ 7],
       [12]])
```

Conclusion, the main difference is that the first one is applying `[1:2]` after the `[:3]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's why:

```
> mat

# output:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])

> mat[:3] # you are selecting the first 3 rows

#output:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

> mat[:3][1:2] # you are selecting the second row only

Output:
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])

> mat[:3,1:2] # you are selecting from the first 3 rows and the second column

Output:
array([[ 2],
       [ 7],
       [12]])
```